# Twilio: Sms is getting send through API but not through studio flow in php

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am sending SMS using twilio and it is working fine when sending directly from php but its is not sending when we send it through flow.

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

define("TWILIO_USERNAME","A******************************");
define("TWILIO_PASSWORD","f******************************");

define("FROM","+12********");
define("MESSAGEFLOW","F**********************");

$sid = TWILIO_USERNAME;
$token = TWILIO_PASSWORD;
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$to = "+919*********";
$joinId         = "41";
/************************ Working Part start ******************/
$body = "This is a test;
$message = $twilio->messages->create(
    $to,
    array(
        'from' => FROM,
        'body' => $body
    )
);
echo 'Message sent! SID: ' . $message->sid;
/*********************** Working part end *****************/ 

/*********************** Not Working Start ****************/
$data = ["parameters" => ["joinID"=>$joinId]];
$flow = $twilio->studio->v2->flows(MESSAGEFLOW);
$flow->executions->create($to, FROM, $data);
/**********************************************************/
```

I am looking for the second part to be working. Let me know what issue could be possible?